# problema ao conectar mysql com java utilizando jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, jdbc

```
LoginDAO.java:

public class LoginDAO {
 private static String sql = "select * from login where login=? and senha=?";
 private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escola";
 private static String username = "root";
 private static String password = "";

public boolean conectar (String login, String senha) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, login);
        st.setString(2, senha);
        ResultSet resp = st.executeQuery();
        if (resp.next()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados!");
    }
    return false;
    }
 }

 Login.java:

@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");
    LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();
    if (dao.conectar(login, senha)) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("login", login);

        return "index.html";
    } else {
        return "sobre.html";
    }

}
```

O arquivo **mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar** foi adicionado na pasta *referenced libraries* quando coloquei no build path.

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message: Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados!

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados!
    br.com.lerolero.dao.LoginDAO.conectar(LoginDAO.java:26)
    br.com.lerolero.web.Login.execute(Login.java:34)
    br.com.lerolero.web.Controller.service(Controller.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando a declaração abaixo parece existir um erro que pode estar causando o problema em questão:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

O nome do driver a ser carregado é:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Uma outra dica é não generalizar a captura de exceções, pois [dificulta a rastreabilidade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea) do problema.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados!");
}
```

Prefira tratar de forma separada nesse caso, facilitando verificar qual foi o método que uma situação inesperada aconteceu. Se olhar as chamadas do bloco try verá:

- [public static Class forName(String className) throws
  ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)
- [public static Connection getConnection(String url) throws
  SQLException](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436202/problema-ao-conectar-mysql-com-java-utilizando-jdbc)
- [PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws
  SQLException](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436202/problema-ao-conectar-mysql-com-java-utilizando-jdbc)
- [void setString(int parameterIndex, String x) throws SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-)
- [ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--)
- [boolean next() throws SQLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--)

A partir disto, escolha aprimorar seu bloco catch com as exceções que podem ser lançadas.

Comment: consegui resolver. Mudei o catch e para "**Driver**" como você falou e descobri que tava dando uma ClassNotFoundException porque  o arquivo **.jar** do jdbc tem que estar dentro da pasta **lib** no diretório **WEB-INF** e não na _referenced libraries_, sendo que foi o próprio eclipse que adicionou o .jar na _referenced libraries_. Thanks!